# Toggle between function in Unity

Tags: c#, unityscript

I want to toggle between function with the left mouse click. So basically, I want my the screen to start with displaying `func1`(`func1` is activated), then when you press the left mouse button `func1` gets deactivated and `func2` gets activated, and then when you press left mouse button again `func2` gets deactivated and `func3` gets activated and when you press the left mouse button again `func3` gets deactivated and `func1` get activated and this keeps looping.

```
bool tappedOnce = true;
    bool tappedTwice = false;
    bool tappedThrice = false;

    void func1() {print("func1");}
    void func2() {print ("func2");}
    void func3() {print ("func3");}
    void toggle()
    {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)&& tappedOnce == false){tappedOnce = true; func1();}

       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)&& tappedOnce && tappedTwice == false ){func2(); tappedTwice = true;}
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)&& tappedOnce && tappedTwice && tappedThrice == false){func3(); tappedOnce = false; tappedTwice = false;}

    }
```

*Asking it here because this question was marked off topic on - game development stack exchange - and they suggested me to ask the question here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching between more than two different functionalities, I recommend using an integer and a switch case statement like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseTest : MonoBehaviour {

//conditional
private int clickNumber;

//run code
void Update () 
{
    toggle();
}

//methods to run
void func0() {Debug.Log ("func0");}
void func1() {Debug.Log ("func1");}
void func2() {Debug.Log ("func2");}
void func3() {Debug.Log ("func3");}

//conditional code
void toggle()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        clickNumber += 1;

    switch (clickNumber)
    {
    case 0:
        func0();
        break;

    case 1:
        func1();
        break;

    case 2:
        func2();
        break;

    case 3:
        func3();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    //set clickNumber to 0 when greater than the number of methods
    if(clickNumber > 3)
        clickNumber = 0;
}

}
```

Change the number of the last if statement to add more functions to the list.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't go back to function 1 from function 2.

Comment: It cycles through the methods in increasing order. If you want to cycle backwards through them, add something like `if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)){clickNumber += -1;}`

Comment: I mean function 3* sorry. It is not going back to function 0 from function 3

Comment: Hmm, works fine for me. Try moving the `if(clickNumber > 3)` if statement to just before the switch statement (just after the `if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))`). Also make sure that this is saved as a C# script named MouseTest and it is attached to a gameobject.

Comment: Why was the answer unaccepted? What' wrong with the script?